# SP Timer Job - is it possible to call a SP timer job via a class or from a button click event?

Tags: timer-jobs

I was just wondering if it's possible to call a timer job from a button click or some logic in a custom solution?

If so do, please provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.execute) method of your job definition. See [this post](http://www.sharepoint4arabs.com/aymanelhattab/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=61) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Is it to test the Timer Job ?

In that case - write all your logic in a seperate class and take the input (according) to your TimerJob (SPFarm, SPWebApp etc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this sort of thing but this [link](http://sakarih.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/starting-custom-timer-job-programmatically/) talks about starting a timer job from a button